# Detecting duplicate work at compile time within C++ code

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

lets consider the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar b1, Bar b2) : b1(b1), b2(b2) {}
    void work() {
         b1.work();
         b2.work();
         //something
    }
    Bar& b1;
    Bar& b2;
};

struct Bar {
    void work() { /* something */ }
};

int main() {
    Bar a, b;
    a.work();
    //something...
    Foo c(a,b);
    c.work();
    //something...
}
```

The way I wrote that (or intended to write it), a.work() will get executed twice. But let's say, I, as the programmer know, that executing it twice is a waste of execution time and let's say this was part of a far more complex piece of software where it would be far too troublesome to keep track manually what work is and isn't done.

Obviously I could store some boolean flag in Bar and check every single time whether the work has been done already, but I want to know, if there is some way where I can already catch that at compile time. Because at compile time it is already clear that the work had been done.

Comment: Dirty way: preprocessor macro definition inside `work()`:`#ifndef ALREADY_DONE #define ALREADY_DONE (..routine..) #endif`

Comment: @Suthiro How will that work? It's the _pre_ processor.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings after second thought, you're right - it would not, however I think it is possible to achieve with preprocessor.

Comment: @Suthiro I don't

Comment: Do you want to diagnose/spot the second call, or merely silently make it a no-op? What is your requirement?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings My requirement/motivation is to have the redundant work eliminated with minimal runtime cost without having some future library user to think about the internal structure of a possibly very complicated composed object.

(Before someone points it out, I understand that it is premature to think about optimizing away booleans, but if there was an elegant way to do this, I would have liked to have considered it in my later design.)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you are right - it is impossible. My memory defied me.

Comment: If you need a thread safe version at runtime you can use [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

The compiler is capable of *some* static analysis, and if you *could* ask it to diagnose this condition, it may be able to do so in some simple cases. But as soon as you have a non-trivial flow (runtime `if` conditions, for example), that goes out of the window very quickly. That's probably part of the reason that nobody has created such a programmable feature for compilers: high complexity, with negligible utility.

It may be possible to program some third-party static analysers (or create one!) to diagnose your simple case, but again that's a lot of work for handling only the most trivial cases that you can already spot with your eyes.

Instead, you could make `work()` happen in the `Bar` constructor. Then it's impossible to do the work twice on the same object. However, performing large quantities of work in a constructor is often frowned upon.

I would indeed keep a state flag within `Bar`, and return `false` from a subsequent `work()`, by maintaining the value of that flag accordingly. As a bonus, stick an assertion in the function before returning `false` so that you catch violations during your testing.

The state flag doesn't have to be a boolean; it can be an `enum`. Robust state machines inside your objects can be very helpful.

That being said, I'd advise revisiting your current approach where you pass references to things into other things that do work on them; it's not an easy-to-follow design, and this is only a simple example of your design! You may wish to consider passing some single-use proxy type instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. Have a function pointer within the `Bar` object and in `work()` function call the `pointer`. In the constructor, define the pointer to be the actual work function. At the end of the function, reassign the pointer to be an empty function.

In this case, the first execution will do the job. But later executions will do nothing (also not checking the `boolean` flag)

```
struct Bar {
  typedef void (*Bar::fptr_t)();
  Bar() : fptr(actual_work) {}
  void actual_work() {
    /*something*/;
    fptr = &Bar::empty_work;
  }

  void empty_work() {}
  void work() {fptr();}
  fptr_t fptr;
};
```

Something like above.

Comment: That's actually a good idea (assuming the OP doesn't need to _diagnose_ the second call, merely make it a no-op). Though it's basically the same as the `bool` idea while only adding indirection.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings maybe you're right, but in `boolean` case, the program will every time check for the boolean value. I know, that checking is not the worst operation and is very trivial to be done. But if the question was about to do no more operations that needed, this is a good example, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But wouldn't that make it impossible for the compiler to inline the actual work in case it deemed that reasonable? If that were the case, I would lean more towards your other answer that states I should use a boolean.

Comment: As I can guess on runtime, it is impossible to make the function to compile as inline. If you want to make it compile as an inline function, the boolean is the solution, but if there's no need for inline, both are applicable.

Comment: @Ikaros I just thought about your question. The quick answer is, that in this like approaches, you always end up with function pointers (be it a virtual function within a class, which is derived or a solution like provided). In that case, the execution will dereference the pointer, get the actual pointer to the function. Therefore, no words about inline functions for this like approaches.

Comment: [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) anyone?

Comment: @super I'm not familiar. Will have a look.

Comment: @super Are you familiar with the implementation? And did you notice, that it also does the check on runtime? If it does runtime, are our/my methods worse?

Comment: @arsdever I think the big difference is that `std::call_once` is thread safe, and thus probably has some more overhead if you don't need that. Guessing that the implementation is very similar to your example. Pointing it out just since there are a lot of things in the standard library that I don't know about and re-inventing the wheel is never smart.

Comment: @arsdever I'd argue that checking a `bool` is cheaper than dereferencing a pointer to call a function. Also, with the `bool`, you can do other things with it, whereas you can't check "is the function empty?" if you wanted to. But we're both splitting hairs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at compile time it isn't obvious, whether the code was executed or not. Suppose you have an if statement and within it, you call `a.work()`. How does the compiler know, whether at that time the `a.work()` was executed? As you say, don't think, that the `if` statement is very simple (suppose, it is looking for some external signal and executes the code depending on that signal). The best way to avoid the behavior is to keep a boolean.